# How to send binary SMS?

Tags: sms

Is there any standard way to send a custom binary SMS supported by Android OS (4.2.2) or through free but third-party support? I mean - could I somewhere enter, for example:

```
0x23 0xAB 0x12 0x56 0xFF
```

and send it as a binary SMS, not a text SMS? I am developing an app which receives binary messages and I would like to test it.

I could write my own app, of course, but I would prefer using some existing and reliable way.

Comment: Hi dear Vojta, Did you had any success with `SMS Server`? I can send text messages successfully, but for binary messages I receive nothing! Does they need any special header or footer in binary mode? For example I couldn't send `30303030` in binary mode instead of `0000` in text mode. Any suggestion? And moreover, which port shall I use?

Comment: @Abraham Hi, yes, SMS Server worked perfectly as far as I remember, even for binary messages. You have to write a special app for receiving them, because the standard Android SMS client receives text messages only. The port is up to you; it must be the same port your Android app listens to.

Comment: Thank you dear Vojta. _Android SMS client receives text messages only._ So, the configuration messages (I think they called _CP Messages_) that can carry GPRS settings, MMS setting and so on, are some type of text messages? (Because I didn't installed any special application on my handset to listen a specific port, but it's capable of receiving these kind of messages).

Comment: Anyway, do you have any idea, how I can generate these CP Messages? Am I need to OTA keys for them or they are just like ordinary messages but with a specific format only?

Comment: @Abraham Sorry, I have no experience with CP messages. By "Android client" I meant the default Android SMS app, which cannot process binary messages (at least as far as I know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this works, but there's an app called [SMS Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.domm.sms) with the following description:

> Send binary sms messages on specifics ports. Indicated to test J2ME
>   sms applications that receive messages on specifics ports. This
>   application does not send free SMS.

Answer (score 1):

Intriguing question.

I'm not sure cell carriers support binary SMS. Have you considered encoding your data as base64 string and sending it?

There will be length limits on the message. I heard that you can include UTF text in the metadata of a png image sent via MMS, several megabytes worth.

Another idea I had is to encode data within the MMS image, each pixel = 256^3 bits or 16,777,216 combinations, a.k.a. 3 bytes per pixel.